# CABasicAnimation activity indicator causes background processing to take 300% longer

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation, xcode-instruments

I am performing a very simple animation for a custom activity indicator as follows:

```
var iconView: UIImageView!

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 2 * M_PI
animation.repeatCount = .infinity
animation.duration = 1.25
iconView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: animation.keyPath)
```

iconView just displays a 96x96 pixel image that is rotated with the animation code shown.

This works fine, but when the animation is used, my background process takes over 310% longer! The background process is done in a NSBlockOperation in a NSOperationQueue:

```
public var backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
backgroundQueue.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated

let operation1 = NSBlockOperation()
operation1.queuePriority = NSOperationQueuePriority.VeryHigh
operation1.qualityOfService = .UserInitiated
```

In the following Time Instrument trace archive, the first trace is done with the animation and takes about 1 minute and 24 seconds. The only difference with the second trace is I disabled the CABasicAnimation code above and the same processing takes 27 seconds!

[Time Instruments Traces](http://3DTOPO.com/Time-Instruments.trace.zip)

I have examined the profile and can't find any reason why it would take so much longer. I thought it might have been that I was using a UIVisualEffectView view for the background of the custom activity indicator, but disabling that didn't have any marked improvement (disabled for the traces above). Any insight or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Update: using a UIActivityIndicatorView it takes a much more reasonable 29 seconds (versus 27 without any indicator).

EDIT: Here is what the trace without the animation looks like:
[image: Time Profile without animation]

And the trace with the animation:
[image: Time Profile with animation]

Comment: do you change the state of your animation inside this background operation? if so are you sure its your actual operation thats taking longer or just the animation taking longer to go away (we cant open that time instruments trace)

Comment: No I don't change the state until the background processing is finished and I am sure its processing the data not just waiting for it to go away. I'm surprised you can't open the Instruments file, is there a reason?

Comment: its seems its locked to your developer profile. "I don't change the state until the background processing is finished" that doesnt quite answer my question, even if the processing is finished you may still be changing the state on a background thread and not the main thread (which will lead to wierd behaviour), maybe post some code where you remove your animation. but if you genuinely arent changing its state on a background thread then im not sure what the problem could be

Comment: I don't think that is the issue because when I drop in an UIActivityIndicatorView in the same exact object that is doing the animation and change nothing else - the problem does not occur. Also, the Instruments shows the time being used in the function doing the processing, not waiting for the "receiveImagePrepNotice" method to be called (see edit I posted screenshots of the two traces).

Comment: Interestingly too you will might notice that all the processing in the highlighted method takes longer: the TDTFaceDetector method, the equalArea function, the convertImageToGrayScale method, etc.

Comment: hmm very odd, not sure what the problem could be, sorry